# Is $SU(N)$ with $N>5$ ruled out as a GUT?

Tags: group-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

Reading the "mainstream" sources, the candidates for GUT gauge groups are $SU(5)$, $SO(10)$ and $E_6$

Yet I understand for ranks 5 and 6, $SU(6)$ and $SU(7)$ also have complex representations (and of course, encompass the SM group since they encompass $SU(5)$).

Looking at the literature, I find a number of papers about $SU(6)$ models in particular, taking various approaches to the symmetry breakdown etc.

With my limited knowledge, these papers don't feel 'crackpoty' and they got decent citation counts. Is there an overarching reason why $SO(10)$ is generally considered as *the* rank-5 option, and not $SU(6)$?

Comment: The standard model fermions fit neatly into SO(10) representations - a 16 of SO(10) equals one standard model generation plus a right-handed neutrino. On the other hand, reps of SU(6) etc will have many extra unobserved fermions.